# What can I use for an easy iPhone speaker?

Tags: technology, phone

I love my music loud and I was wondering if there’s a hack for an easy iPhone speaker? I’ve tried putting my phone inside a cup but it’s still not loud enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I love my music loud

I also love the music loud, especially if there is good bass.

> I’ve tried putting my phone inside a cup but it’s still not loud enough.

Yes, that is to be expected. If you want more sound energy than the phone can give, then you need a powered amplifier. Powered = from wall socket or from batteries.

---

I also have another restriction: I do not want to anger my neighbors with my music.

My solution: I use **headphones**. I have two pairs: one wireless for convenience, and another one wired when the wireless needs to be recharged.

Because all the energy of the speaker goes into the ear instead of being broadcasted in the entire room, very loud sound is perceived with very small power.

---

> I was wondering if there’s a hack for an easy iPhone speaker

There is a good reason why concert halls do not use iPhones and iPhone speakers for sound: these devices are not able to provide the level of sound required.

---

> I’ve tried putting my phone inside a cup but it’s still not loud enough

You may additionally try to put the phone into a metal cooking pot. You might have to use a lid for the pot too. The size of the pot should matter, so feel free to experiment with different pot sizes / shapes.

But be aware that the sound might get quite distorted.